# Crashlytics console shows loader, Crashlytics enabled & Setup properly but unable to get the crash reports?

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

[image: Crashlytics Console Screenshot]

I have an Android app with two Build Types. One is `Debug` and the other one is `Release` the **issue** I am facing is that my `Debug Build` is sending crash reports to Crashlytics and my `Release Build` is not sending any crash reports to the Crashlytics console and shows the loading icon as shown in the Screenshot.

The difference in both the variants is that one has **Proguard** enabled and other one doesn't.

Build Types in `build.gradle(:app)` look like this:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig getSigningConfig()
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }

    }
```

I have followed the complete for setting up the crashlytics mentioned here: [Firebase Crashlytics Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android)

**Here is the checklist**

> 1. Enabled Crashlytics From Console
> 2. Added the Crashlytics Gradle plugin as a buildscript dependency in project level `build.gradle` with *version:2.3.0*
> 3. Applied gradle plugin in `build.gradle(:app)`
> 4. Initilized Crashlytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Found out that the issue is related to this flag here:

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
  mappingFileUploadEnabled false
}
```

In the case of `Debug` build Proguard is not enabled so the mapping file is not created as well so there is no need to upload the **mappings** file.

But in the case of `Release` build, I have enabled the `proguard` So, technically I need to enable the mappings file to be uploaded so that crashlytics reports can be sent to the console and properly reported.

Changing the above code in `Release` to this fixed the issue.

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
  mappingFileUploadEnabled true
}
```

[Got clue from the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_7)

After Fixing that issue I came across another issue while creating the signed apk `The Host name may not be empty` and you can [follow this for the fix.](http://The%20Host%20name%20may%20not%20be%20empty)

Cheers :)

Comment: link not working for Host name may not be empty solution. could you please share the solution?